# Lyapunovs stability definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Id like to know how to check out if a point is stable using Lyapunovs definition. The definition itself as Ive seen it on wikipedia is hard to understand for me.

Let the system be
$$x'=y$$
$$y'=x$$
The fixed point is $(0,0)$. What should I do from here on?

Answer (score 2):

Lyapunov stability means that for any open region $R$ containing the fixed point $p$, you can always pick an open region of initial conditions $S$ containing $p$ so that the system stays within $R$ if it starts within $S$.

I'll emphasise that the region $R$ must contain all points within some distance of the fixed point, so you're not allowed to tune the initial condition except by making it close to $p$.

Your system is easy to solve explicitly:
$$
x(t)=x_0 \cosh(t) +y_0 \sinh(t),\\
y(t)=x_0 \sinh(t) +y_0\cosh(t).
$$

What do the solutions do for large time look like in this case? It's a worthwhile exercise to sketch the phase portrait.

Comment: I dont really understand whar happened here and where your system came from

Comment: I took your system to mean the ODEs $x'(t)=y(t), y'(t)=x(t)$, which I solved with initial conditions $x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0$.  (Differentiate the first equation to get $x''(t)=y'(t)$, which equals $x(t)$ from the second; now you have $x''(t)=x(t)$). Was that the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply Lyapunov's definition of stability you first have to obtain the general solution $\boldsymbol{x}(t)$ and a reference solution $\boldsymbol{x}_{R}(t)$, which is the solution for which we want to assess stability.

The reference solution is your fixed point $\boldsymbol{x}_R(t)=[0,0]^T$.

In order to obtain the general solution, we differentiate the first equation with respect to $t$ to obtain $x''=y'$ plugging this into the second equation will result in one scalar equation:

$$x''=x.\qquad (1)$$

Using Euler's exponential ansatz $x(t)=\exp(\lambda t)$ we obtain:

$$(\lambda^2-1)\exp(\lambda t) = 0 \text{ as } \exp(\lambda t)\neq 0 \implies\lambda^2-1=0 \implies \lambda_{1,2}=\pm 1.$$

The general solution of $(1)$ is then given by the linear combination of the two exponential solutions.

$$x(t)=c_1\exp(t)+c_2\exp(-t)$$

Using your first differential equation $x'=y$ we can conclude:

$$y(t)=c_1\exp(t)-c_2\exp(-t).$$

Note, that often these solutions are reformulated using $\sinh(t)$ and $\cosh(t)$ as Holographer did.

Using $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ we can formulate the general solution as

$$\boldsymbol{x}(t)=[c_1\exp(t)+c_2\exp(-t),c_1\exp(t)-c_2\exp(-t)]^T.$$

From Lyapunov's definition of stability, we need to find a circle (in general a $n$-dimensional ball) of initial conditions radius $\delta$ such that

$$||\boldsymbol{x}(t=t_0)-\boldsymbol{x}_R(t=t_0)||_{2}< \delta \implies ||\boldsymbol{x}(t)-\boldsymbol{x}_R(t)||_{2}< \varepsilon, \text{ for all } t\geq t_0, \varepsilon >0.$$

We can guess that this is not possible because of the $\exp(t)$ term, which blows up to $\infty$ for $t \to \infty$. So what we want to do is to choose an initial condition arbitrarily close to the origin such that we cannot find a $\delta$ for any given $\varepsilon>0$.

Let us use the initial condition $x(t=0)=\kappa$ and $y(t=0)=\kappa$, in which $\kappa >0$ is a arbitrarily small positive number, the resulting solution implied by the general solution is $$\boldsymbol{x}(t)=[\kappa \exp(t),0]^T$$

Now, let us assume we have found a delta such that:

$$||\boldsymbol{x}(t=0)-\boldsymbol{x}_r(t=0)||_2<\delta \implies ||\boldsymbol{x}(t)-\boldsymbol{x}_r(t)||_2=|\kappa|\exp(t)<\varepsilon.$$

It is clear from the last equation that no matter how small we choose $\kappa$ for $t \to \infty$ the $\exp(t)$ term will make the inquality invalid. Hence, there cannot be any initial condition no matter how close to the origin, which can guarantee that we stay close to the origin for all time $t\geq 0$.  Hence the, origin is unstable in the sense of Lyapunov.